# adding a new line character to a row

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, tr

I'd like to extract the 2nd field and transpose it to become a row

```
cat > temp1
1   73
2   74
3   75
```

My approach :

```
cut -f2 temp1 | tr '\n'  '\t' > temp2
```

The result :

```
temp2
73  74  75
```

Understandably, there is a tab separator at the right end of the line but missing a new line character. Is there an simple one-liner to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `paste` instead of `tr`:

```
$ cut -f2 temp1 | paste -s
73  74  75
```

verifying the invisible whitespace

```
$ cut -f2 temp1 | paste -s | od -c
0000000   7   3  \t   7   4  \t   7   5  \n
0000011
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  cat file | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs -n3
  73 74 75
```

and to verify the invisible whitespace per *@glenn jackman*

```
cat file | cut -d' ' -f4 | xargs -n3 |  od -c

0000000   7   3       7   4       7   5  \n
0000011
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to print/emit/give a new line is to use `echo`.

It seems quite simple to add a new line to the file created:

cut -f2 temp1 | tr '\n'  '\t' > temp2
   echo >> temp2

Which could be done in one line as:

```
{ cut -f2 temp1 | tr '\n'  '\t' ; echo ; } > temp2
```

That is: if the trailing tab is not a problem. If it is, you need to either remove it or avoid it being generated, any of this will do it:

```
awk 'NR>1{printf( "%s\t",a)}{a=$2}END{print a}' temp1 >temp2

sed -n 's/[0-9]*[[:blank:]]*//;1{h;d};H;${g;y/\n/\t/;p}' temp1 >temp2

sed 's/[0-9]*[[:blank:]]*//' temp1 | paste -sd '\t' >temp2
```